# Carry Instagram username into autocomplete

Tags: google-chrome, autocomplete

I want my form to get Instagram into a field autocomplete on my own form. So, they complete my form and the Instagram field is filled automatically. But I can see precious little on forums or net about it.

Here's the field they use for login name:

```
<input aria-label="Phone number, username, or email" aria-required="true" autocapitalize="off" autocorrect="off" maxlength="75" name="username" type="text" class="_2hvTZ pexuQ zyHYP" value="stevie.brockard">
```

Specifically Chrome is most important but a cross-browser solution would be best, of course.

Comment: Best I can do so far is set `name="username"` on my field, but it only works if they start typing into it (autofill) not as the form itself (autocomplete).

Comment: It won't let me edit, but the associated code I've got now is: `<label for="TextBoxSocial" class="InputLine">Instagram:</label><input id="TextBoxSocial" name="username" autocomplete="username" />
`